# How can i clone my current installation of ubuntu 13.04 amd64 with UEFI to make live image/CD

Tags: 13.04, backup, uefi, live-cd, cd-image

I want to create a liveCD of my current installed ubuntu 13.04 amd64 (UEFI Mode). So i get back all my installed packages in fresh ubuntu install.

I read some other question but they are for older versions and I install it with UEFI mode.

Edit:
Is there any software that can create a .iso image (liveCD) form my liveUSB of ubuntu 13.04 amd64

Comment: I have not tested this which is why it's a comment and not an answer but take a look here: [MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall)

Comment: very long procedure.. is there any easy way like `Remastersys`. no longer in development.

Comment: No, it is a complex manual task with lots of exceptions and cave-ats. It is easier to get an installer file (ISO), mount that and start hacking away by adding packages.

Comment: @Rinzwind yes you are right but i down't have an iso. I had iso but when i install ubuntu. it format my hard disk and i left only with an liveUSB. so can i use it to re-create an iso for later use.

Answer (score 0):

You unmount the ISO. You install the ISO on a virtual machine such as VirtualBox. Then you copy the file to wherever you want.

Comment: Can you please explain it with more detail/steps. I'm new to ubuntu.